# SQL Server : default values - cannot insert the value NULL into column <UID> table <table> column does not allow nulls

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I think I misunderstand how default values work. I'm learning SQL Server and have imported a test table  with pre-existing values comprised of Chinese words I am learning. The table's name is 我的單詞卡. I was under the impression if I set the default value to `newid()` a UID would be generated without my having to specify it.

My table has the following columns:

[image: Table Settings]

I have specified my query like this:

```sql
USE 单词卡
INSERT INTO  備份 (備份.繁體字, 備份.簡體字, 備份.拼音, 備份.翻譯, 備份.詞源)
VALUES ('曹', '曹', 'cáo', '同類的人，姓，周朝諸侯國名。在今山東西南部。', '曹 is composed of  (originally 㯥 “a pair, couple”) and 曰 “to speak, say,” which indicate the original meaning “opponents or adversaries.')
```

But I still get this error:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'uid', table '单词卡.dbo.備份'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Should it not have automatically populated that with the default value?

Comment: Side note: If you are inserting unicode literals you need to prefix them with N. Example:  `VALUES (N'曹',....)`. That will prevent accidental conversion from ascii to unicode where the results can be different depending on the executing culture of the user running the query.

Comment: Why are all your columns an `nvarchar(MAX)`? Do they all *really* need to store up to 2GB (1 Billion) characters?

Comment: As for the error, I would suggest your column, `uid` doesn't have the default constraint you think it does.

Comment: @Larnu as I mentioned it's a test table I threw together purely for the sake of just having a table with which to experiment. I'm not trying to put this into production.

Comment: Even test tables should be appropriately defined though, @GrantCurell .

Comment: FYI, that image of your table's definition has a * at the end of the name of the tab, meaning it has unsaved changes. You *have* saved the changes to add the default value, right..?

Comment: @Larnu While I appreciate your input I think it best we stay on topic. If I have a question about data types for a test table that I'm going to use for 10 minutes to test things I'll be sure to ask that explicitly.

Comment: Yes to answer your question about saving the value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237065/discussion-between-grant-curell-and-larnu).

Comment: Can you post the *actual* DDL for your table in the question, not an image of a single column in the designer so we can replicate the issue please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your table like this, it should work:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_test](
    [uid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [testData] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [uid] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[_test] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__test_uid]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [uid]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[_test]([testData]) VALUES('AAA')
GO

select * from _test
GO
```

If it's working for you then you just need to replace the name of the table and list your columns like the 'testData' column.